# Firebase authentication swiftui

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui

how to fix this code it. it gives an error that can't push 2 calls must be only one. For this reason my login using firebase authentication doesn't work. i am not great with firebase i don't ge the documentation unfortunately.

// Sign up code in sessionStore

```
func signUp(email: String, password: String, completion: @escaping (_ error: Error?) -> Void) {
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            completion(nil)
            }
        }
    }
```

//sign in code for sign in view - particularly where * is placed is where i get the error that must take in one variable not 2 variables.

```
func signIn() {
        session.signIn(email: email, password: password) { **(result, error)** in
            if let error = error {
                self.error = error.localizedDescription
            } else {
                return
            }
        }
    }
```

// sign in in sessionStore

```
 func signIn(email: String, password: String, completion:@escaping (_ error: Error?) -> Void) {
            Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                completion(nil)
                }
            }
        }
```

// code for sign in in sign in view
also get the same error in the view

```
func signUp() {
        session.signUp(email: email, password: password) {(result,_ error) in
            if let error = error {
                self.error = error.localizedDescription
            } else {
                self.email = ""
                self.password = ""
            }
        }
    }
```

i want to store users id in the firestore so i link a user's account to their data.
Older solutions on stackoverflow don't work and so i want to re-ask this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `sessionStore`, your completion handler only sends back an `Error?`:

```
func signIn(email: String, password: String, completion:@escaping (_ error: Error?) -> Void) {
```

But, you're attempting to use both a `result` and `error` when you call it here:

```
session.signIn(email: email, password: password) { (result, error) in
```

The simplest fix, if you don't need the `result`, is to just change that line to:

```
session.signIn(email: email, password: password) { (error) in
```

Also, you currently aren't sending that error on in `sessionStore`. Add this:

```
func signIn(email: String, password: String, completion:@escaping (_ error: Error?) -> Void) {
            Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                    completion(error) //<-- Here
            } else {
                completion(nil)
                }
            }
        }
```

If you *do* need the `result` in your `signIn` function in your view, you could modify the `signIn` function in `sessionStore` to also return the result:

```
func signIn(email: String, password: String, completion:@escaping (AuthDataResult?,Error?) -> Void) {
  Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result, error) in
    completion(result, error)              
  }
}
```

In that case, you could keep your original `(result, error)` code in your view.

Comment: how about the sign up function in sign up view.

Comment: You would apply exactly the same principal that I illustrated for the `signIn`

Comment: once the user sign in how do i complete it. within the sign in view

Comment: also why is it that once a user signs up they are automatically signed in. i want it to be that once the user signs up the fields set back empty and they must login through the sign in to be signed in to enter the content view.

Comment: Group {
            if (session.session != nil) {
                VStack {
                    Text("Welcome back here user!")
                    Button(action:session.signOut) {
                        Text("Sign out")
                    }
                }
                
            } else {
                SignInView().environmentObject(SessionStore())
            }
        }.onAppear(perform: getUser) // Above is some code on to execute the authentication.

Comment: These seem to be separate questions. Did my answer solve your original problem mentioned in your question?

Comment: yes it did but i still have another question surrounding the original question asked. @jnpdx

Comment: Okay — please mark the answer as accepted. Your follow up questions are not trivial and deserve their own answers and explanations. In fact, I see you’ve already asked another question about it.